# How to create an object in C#

Tags: c#

how can I create an object using the below code? I need to show a message in the console with this object...

```
class TimePeriod { 
    private double seconds;
    public double Hours { 
        get { return seconds / 3600; } 
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    } 
}
```

Is something like this correct?

`TimePeriod time = new TimePeriod(10)`

Comment: You need a constructor for that

Comment: `new TimePeriod { Hours = 10 }`

Comment: Add the constructor `public TimePeriod(int someVariableName){//constructor code here}` to your class

Comment: I am not allowed to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a new object like so:

```
TimePeriod myObject = new TimePeriod();
```

Adding the 10 in the parenthesis is useful when you have Constructors. Read up on those for more information, they are fairly simple.

I don't know what you want to write to the console but it would work something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("The amount of hours is {0}", myObject.Hours);
```

Hopefully this makes sense :)

Comment: What is that {0} used for?

Comment: The {0} is used as a placeholder in the string for a variable you want to substitute in for that position. It makes your code cleaner, for instance:

Instead of writing this:

Console.WriteLine("The amount of hours is " + myObject.Hours);

You can write it this way if you are using more variables in the string to make your code cleaner and easier to read.

Console.WriteLine("The amount of hours is {0}", myObject.Hours);

You can add as many as you need:

Console.Write("You have worked {0} hours and {1} minutes", myObject.Hours, myObject.Minutes);

Comment: Good to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In C#, in order to construct an object while providing parameters to it, you must first create a constructor with that parameter as an input argument:

```
class TimePeriod { 
    public TimePeriod(double seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }
    private double seconds;
    public double Hours { 
        get { return seconds / 3600; } 
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    } 
}
```

Then you can use the syntax you suggested above:

```
TimePeriod period = new TimePeriod(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TimePeriod 
{ 
    private double seconds;

    public TimePeriod (double dSeonds)
    {
        seconds=dSeonds;
        Console.WriteLine("Object Created: "+dSeonds);
    }

    public double Hours { 
        get { return seconds / 3600; } 
        set { seconds = value * 3600; }
    } 
}
```

And create the `Object` of the above class with like this:

```
TimePeriod period = new TimePeriod(10);
```